# Git pull does not pull any files (without error)

Tags: git

I am trying to pull the files and folders from my repository in github but I am not seeing any changes in my remote folder. These are the steps I took.

1. git init
2. git remote add origin /repository/
3. git remote -v
4. git pull origin master

Strangely I am not getting any errors. The request just completes and when I check (ls), I do not see any files being pulled (my repository is not empty). Anybody encountered this issue?

'Git status' yields the following:

```
Initial commit

nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
```

Comment: If you are `init`-ing your repo, why not `clone` it directly instead of making it from scratch?

Comment: same issue if i clone. nothing appears

Comment: Can you show us `git status` or some other output?

Comment: `I am not seeing any changes in my remote folder`. If you pull there won't be any changes in the remote folder.

Comment: `git remote add origin` should print error since it requires the URL of the remote.

Comment: I know this is a bit pedantic, but git doesn’t pull files. It pulls commits.

Comment: then how do I "initiate" my server folder to reflect the repository in github? (i tried gitclone already)

Comment: Try cloning the remote repo to a new location. Also check which branches are being used, the commits might exist under a different branch than master.

Comment: Any further progress?

Comment: do you have submodules in your repository? then you may need to update it first.

Answer (score 0):

Because

> Git pull does not pull any files (without error)

therefore there are nothing on remote repository. Simple, Clearly, Logical, and easy-to-understand.

Let's push something to remote repository, or working collaboration with other, require other team member push something to remote repository, then you can pull something.